# "Has shown to provide significant performance gain"

Tags: tense

This is the correct version on the text.

> Method A has shown to provide a significant performance gain for method B in a general dataset. However there is a possibility that method A could decrease the efficiency of method B in some scenarios.

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> Method A has shown to provide significant performance gain for method B in a general dataset, however there is a possibility that method A could decrease the efficiency of method B in some scenarios.

Comment: So what is your concern? Comma or an article?

Comment: the concern is, is this grammatically correct?

Comment: I have changed the final word from _is_ to _in_. I hope this is what you intended.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not grammatically correct. To be grammatically correct, it has to be this:

> Method A has {**been** shown / **proved** / **proven** [CHOOSE ONE]} to provide **a** significant performance gain for method B in a general data set**;** however, there is a possibility that method A **will** decrease the efficiency of method B in some scenarios.

Comment: Why it is "a" significant performance gain, since performance gain is not something that is countable?

Comment: @william007: "There were performance gains throughout the system" is perfectly grammatical & semantically sound. The head noun of the phrase "performance gain" is a count noun: _gain_. That makes "performance" a nominal adjective that modifies "gain". When the system is modified, there are **gains** & **losses**. I found a few instances of the phrase doing a Google search: "the performance **gains** for RAIDed SSDs is marginal", "the performance **gains** are generally impressive", & "see if the RAID 0 offers any performance **gains** or pitfalls compared to". Plural nouns are count nouns.

Comment: Technical writers often write the way they speak. In the biomed field, doctors & biologists do too. That means that they write jargon & abbreviate the English. Just because it's published doesn't mean it's good or even correct English, just that it's standard & understandable jargon, even if it's ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem with the second version is the intransitive use of *show*. This may occur, and it may be possible to argue its grammaticality, but it is not, I suspect, widespread. Many readers will expect *has been shown*, and there is no reason to disappoint them.

The second problem is the use of *however* as a coordinator. This is becoming more frequent, but it is not yet universally accepted. It would therefore be advisable to change it for *but* or to use it to start a new sentence or to put a semi-colon rather than a comma after *dataset*, as in the first version.

Thirdly, the absence of the indefinite article before *significant performance gain* is a little unusual, but not necessarily ungrammatical. When used to make a generic reference the zero article (that is, no article) is normally used with plural and uncountable nouns. *Gain* is generally a countable noun, but I can just about see it as uncountable in your sentence. However, the absence of *a*, like the intransitive use of *show*, might stop some readers in their tracks, so on pragmatic, if no other, grounds, it might be as well to use it.